# How to reclaim disk space after deletes on read-write indices in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In an attempt to free up disk space, i'm running regular deletes on my elasticsearch indexes for unused documents. I was going to run force merge to actually free up the space, but my indices are not read only.

From the elasticsearch documentation, "Force merge should only be called against read-only indices. Running force merge against a read-write index can cause very large segments to be produced..." [ElasticSearch Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html#indices-forcemerge)

Is there a proper way to expunge deleted documents from read-write indices?